# how to update several line text field in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a several line text field in MySQL like this :

```
main: .item-list

title: h2 > a

description: .entry > p

content: .entry
```

how can i select or update this  ?
i just want to update second value like ".item-list" in main line

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: It seems to me a broken database/table design, if you need to get/update parts of a fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET <field>=REPLACE(<field>,"main: .item-list","main: .newitem-list") WHERE <condition>
```

Do it for every main value you have.

Also consider seriously to store that values in fields rather than in a text field.

Comment: thank you for answering ....how can i select second value ? (.item-list )

Comment: thank you for answering ....how can i select second value ? (.item-list )... i want to use code like this : what is main value  in row ? main value = ".item-list"

Comment: All you can do is do a SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <field> like '%main: .item-list%'. That should show you all the records containig the .item-list .... But the correct way should be to create a new column. Be in mind that this search could take a long time if you have a lot of records. Having one column you can create an index and speed up the searches a lot!